# Does C destroy return variable before the closing brace?

Tags: c

Somebody told me that in `C` (and `C++`) that the variable present in a return statement is destroyed before closing brace of the function.

Ex -

```
int func() {
    int a = 10;
    return a; // I was told that a is destroyed here
}
```

Does it really happen that way? If yes, how does the function return value to the calling function?

My intuition tells me that the variable value is pushed on to stack at the return value and when it goes back to the calling function, the stack top is popped there by getting the return value. Not sure if I'm correct.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between returning a *value* and returning a pointer or reference.

Comment: @PaulR I know about pointers. This is not related to pointers.

Comment: *How* values are returned to the parent function, and exactly *where* and *when* local variables are "destroyed", is implementation specific. It could be different for different compilers.

Comment: You can also, for instance, `return 2*a+17;` which should make it clear that whatever is returned is a _value_, not a variable on the stack.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg;  I do not understand your point. See my updated answer. I quoted what I read in the Dietel book.

Comment: @haccks The quote is about how the program returns to the original location and about the location of the function parameters; it doesn't mention where the return value is stored.

Comment: @NileshGovindrajan Maybe you simply worded it wrong, but there is no such thing as a _return variable_. Are you more familiar with Pascal? Pascal does have the notion of a return variable.

Comment: @MrLister No, haven't worked with Pascal and I wasn't referring to a _return variable_. I'm interested in _how exactly_ does the value get returned to the caller and whether my guess is right about stack and from the answers & comments, it seems yes.

Comment: no, you are not right about stack, read again.

Comment: @NileshGovindrajan The statement `return a;` copies the contents of `a` into the variable the caller uses to store it before returning.

Comment: @NileshGovindrajan You say "I wasn't referring to a return variable" but you were, in the question. Twice.

Comment: @MrLister modified my question to clear that ambiguity.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath As per haccks answer, that's the best layman explanation. Although as you commented there, it's for x86 only. That's enough for me, as the question came out of a similar context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does the function return value to the calling function?

Your intuition is right (partially). In some architecture the value is stored at stack and get popped when returning to the caller.  But keep in mind that a value is returned from a function, not the variable itself.

#### [C: How to Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013299044X): Ch-5: C Functions:

> When a program calls a function, the called function must know how to return to its
>   caller, so the return address of the calling function is pushed onto the **program execution stack** (sometimes referred to as the function call stack).
>
> **The program execution stack also contains the memory for the local variables used in
>   each invocation of a function during a program’s execution**. This data, stored as a portion of the program execution stack, is known as the **activation record** or **stack frame** of the function call. When a function call is made, the activation record for that function call is pushed onto the program execution stack. When the function returns to its caller, the activation record for this function call is popped off the stack and **those local variables are no longer known to the program**.

---

**EDIT:** As others mentioned is comments that this is implementation specific I changed my mind.
For x86 [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) says:

> Calling conventions describe the interface of called code:
>   1. The order in which atomic (scalar) parameters, or individual parts of a complex parameter, are allocated
>   2. **How parameters are passed (pushed on the stack, placed in registers, or a mix of both)**
>   3. Which registers the callee must preserve for the caller
>   4. How the task of preparing the stack for, and restoring after, a function call is divided between the caller and the callee
>   **There are often subtle differences in how various compilers implement these conventions**.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, this is implementation specific. In the case of `int`, it's more likely a register than a stack location.

Comment: indeed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions - and that's just one architecture...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath; Thanks for the link. I never knew that these conventions are implementation defined. There is too much to learn :(

Answer (score 5):

> Does C destroy return variable before the closing brace?

Yes ... sort of.

Local variables go out of scope at the end of a method, and after that, they cease to be accessible.

In C, that simply means that the storage for the variable itself becomes available for other uses.  But there is no active "destruction" of the variable.

In C++, the variable's destructor (if there is one) will be invoked when the variable goes out of scope.

At an implementation level, the storage space for local variables is *typically* managed using a stack.  But I don't think this is mandated by the respective language specifications.

---

It is also important to note that we are talking about variables, not values.  In your example, the value of the variable is going to be returned to the caller (*vide* the `return` statement) and will continue to exist beyond the `}` ...